# how to make only one record in grid as non editable using Kendoui

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui

I want to make only one cell in grid as non-editable using Kendo ui. So that it should not be delete, edit from table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can create conditional logic and hide the edit buttons based on the row model. [Here](http://jsbin.com/UcURobUr/3/edit) is a small example using the dataBound event of the Grid.

```
         dataBound: function (){
           var grid = this;
           var trs = this.tbody.find('tr').each(function(){
             var item = grid.dataItem($(this));
             if( item.UnitPrice % 5 == 0) {
               $(this).find('.k-grid-edit,.k-grid-delete').hide();
             }

           });               
         },
```